# How to iterate Map in a scripted data source of BIRT

Tags: javascript, birt

I am working on BIRT reports and for that I am using POJO as input to my report design.I have one method in that POJO whose return type is MAP(collection) and I want to iterate that MAP in a scripted data source of BIRT so that I can use key and values from it.Please do let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching on how to iterate Collection(MAP) in BIRT script, I have found a many ways to do it.Here I am giving a sample code which works for me.

1. Consider "ReportOverview" as a MAP which having Key-value pairs.
2. In a Script "Open" of a data set add below code :

   ```
   // Get the ReportOverview object.
   reportOverview =reportContext.getAppContext().get("overview");

   iter=reportOverview.iterator();      
   counter = 0;
   ```
3. In a fetch Script you will get a value from each iteration by adding below code:

   ```
   if(iter.hasNext()) {
       row["statusCount"]=iter.next();
       counter++;
       return true;
   } 
   return false;
   ```